# Can not arrange item order in Plone 4's navigation portlet

Tags: python, navigation, plone, portlet

So I added this navigation portlet for one of my folder objects. There are 10 child nodes within this folder. The portlet orders the items by their creation date which I do not want, but I could not find a way to change this order. Do I have to re-added these 10 objects by the order I want or is there something I am missing here?

Comment: What is `sortAttribute` set to in `ZMI` -> `portal_properties` -> `navtree_properties`?

Comment: Are you sure? That's the value for `sortOrder`, not `sortAttribute`; the latter should be set to `getObjPositionInParent` normally.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. Ye, it's set to `getObjPositionInParent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default setup sorts items by their container ordering (the `getObjPositionInParent` index in the catalog).

You can alter the ordering of items within a container by dragging them by their ordering handle:

[image: order draghandle in Plone]

This is on the folder contents view (`Contents`).

If you need to alter the default sorting parameter because *all* your content should always be sorted alphabetically or by publication date or similar, you'll have to change the navigation tree parameters in the ZMI; find the `portal_properties` tool in the ZMI, within which you'll find the `navtree_properties` property sheet. Change the `sortAttribute` property to the name of a different catalog index to sort results by.

If you have created a custom Archetypes folder type, make sure it inherits from `plone.app.folder.base.BaseBTreeFolder`. When using Dexterity, the `plone.dexterity.content.Container` base class is orderable by default.

Comment: Okay, I see the ordering handle for Plone folder objects. But I created this object which based on ATCTFolder dose not seem to have this handle thing. Is that because I used wrong base? `class Region(base.ATCTFolder):`

Comment: @tman: Right, that base class does not support ordering. I've updated my answer to extend to custom types.